# why alert dialog is opening first and then content is loaded in it

Tags: android

```
db.collection("Orderers").document(mAuth.getUid()).collection("OpenOrders").document(orderid.getText().toString()).get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {

                        DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = task.getResult();
                        if(documentSnapshot.exists()) {
                            final String status = (String) task.getResult().get("Status");

                            if (status.equals("in progress")) {

                                final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(openorderdetails.this);
                                @SuppressLint("InflateParams") final View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.ratingbar, null);
                                final LinearLayout psrate = mView.findViewById(R.id.psrate);
                                final LinearLayout storerate = mView.findViewById(R.id.storerate);
                                final LinearLayout tohide = mView.findViewById(R.id.tohide);
                                final TextView ss = mView.findViewById(R.id.ss);
                                Button b1 = mView.findViewById(R.id.b1);
                                ImageView dp = mView.findViewById(R.id.dp);
                                final RatingBar ratebar = mView.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);

                                String dm = task.getResult().getString("DeliveryMethods");
                                String stid = task.getResult().getString("StoreId");

                                if (dm.equals("PickUp")) {

                                    db.collection("Stores").document(stid).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                                            storename = (String) task.getResult().get("StoreName");
                                            Log.e("sn", storename);
                                            psrate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                            storerate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                            ss.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                            ss.setText(storename);
                                            ratebar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                            tohide.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                        }
                                    });

                                } else if (dm.equals("PersonalShopper")) {

                                    psrate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    storerate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    ss.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    //Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(pshopperimage).into(dp);
                                    try{
                                        Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()) //Context
                                                .load(pshopperimage) //URL/FILE
                                                .into(dp);//an ImageView Object to show the loaded image;
                                    }
                                    catch (Exception ignored){

                                    }
                                    ss.setText(fname + " " + lname);
                                    ratebar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    tohide.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                }

                                builder.setCancelable(false);


                                ratebar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {
                                        rateValue = rating;
                                        //  Toast.makeText(openorderdetails.this, "" + rating, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                    }
                                });

                                builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                                        String rateValue1 = String.valueOf(rateValue);

                                        upload1(rateValue1);
                                    }
                                });

                                b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View v) {

                                        Intent i = new Intent(openorderdetails.this, openorderdetails.class);
                                        i.putExtra("Orderid", orderid.getText().toString());
                                        startActivity(i);
                                        finish();
                                    }
                                });


                                builder.setView(mView);
                                AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                                alertDialog.show();

                            }
                        }
                    }

                });
```

I am creating an alert dialog, alert dialog will be called when a button is clicked, my problem is when I click on the button alert is opening with ok button first and then rest of the content of my alert dialog is loading.I want the alert dialog to appear only once with the complete content in it where am I doing wrong can anyone suggest me please,Thanks in advance

Comment: you are loading image in alertdailog so i suggest you to use async task for loading data in it

Comment: why you didn't using `progressbar` in your `alertDialog`? maybe it can help you...

Comment: @MiladBahmanabadi Right, another way Swapna you can use progressbar in alert dailog

Comment: ok, I will try.

Comment: no use if I use progress dialog also

Answer (score 0):

you check the status `if (status.equals("in progress"))` status is true than you call this `alertDialog.show();` so direct open the alert box if you check one more condition then you call this method `alertDialog.show();`

Hope it's properly working.

hope it's helpful for you.

Comment: yes, and also add this method  builder.setPositiveButton inside the condition

Comment: yes builder.setpositivebutton() is also inside the condition

Comment: add one more condition inside this  if (status.equals("in progress")) condition